# How do I toggle between List and Grid view (the image must change together)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
**#Original Component**

        import React from 'react';
        import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
        import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
        import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
        import { Dropdown } from './Dropdown';
        import FormatAlignLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FormatAlignLeft';
        import FormatAlignCenterIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FormatAlignCenter';
        import FormatAlignRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FormatAlignRight';
        import FormatAlignJustifyIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FormatAlignJustify';
        import ToggleButton from '@material-ui/lab/ToggleButton';
        import ToggleButtonGroup from '@material-ui/lab/ToggleButtonGroup';
        import { Gallery1 } from './Gallery1';




        const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
            section: {
                paddingBottom: 10, 
                marginTop: 15, 
                borderBottom:"1px solid #ddd",
                width:'100%',
                flexDirection: 'row',
                display:'flex',

            },
            alignmentCenterObject:{
                alignSelf:'center',
            },
            alignmentLower:{
                paddingTop:8,
            },
            alignmentUpper:{
                paddingBottom:2,
            },


            
        }));
        
        export function Rightpanel () {
            const classes = useStyles();
            const [alignment, setAlignment] = React.useState('left');

            const handleAlignment = (event, newAlignment) => {
              setAlignment(newAlignment);
            };



        return(




            <div style={{padding: "2em"}}>
                <Grid container spacing={2} className={classes.section} >
                        <Grid item className={classes.alignmentUpper}>
                {/* //Results */}
                            <Typography variant = 'h3'> Results </Typography>
                            <Typography variant = 'caption' > 5105 records (s) found </Typography>

                        </Grid>

                {/* //Sort By Function */}
                        <Grid item xs={9} sm={9} md={9} lg={9} className={classes.alignmentCenterObject} >

                            <Dropdown label="Sort By" choices={["Date descending", "Date ascending", "Altitude descending", "Altitude ascending"]}/>
                        
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item >
                        <ToggleButtonGroup
                            value={alignment}
                            exclusive
                            onChange={handleAlignment}
                            aria-label="text alignment"
                            fullWidth
                            className={classes.alignmentLower}
                            >
                            <ToggleButton aria-label="left aligned">
                                <FormatAlignLeftIcon />
                            </ToggleButton>
                            <ToggleButton value="center" aria-label="centered">
                                <FormatAlignCenterIcon />
                            </ToggleButton>
                        </ToggleButtonGroup>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
                           <Gallery1/> 
                        </Grid>





                </Grid>
        

            </div>
        );
        }
        

**#Gallery Component**
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Gallery from 'react-photo-gallery';

 {/* must put: npm install react-photo-gallery */}
 {/* reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/r48lm1jopq?file=/src/index.js:3907-3958*/}


 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    growingBox: {
        flexGrow:1,

    },

}));



const photos = [
    {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/2ShvY8Lf6l0/800x599",
        width: 4,
        height: 3
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/Dm-qxdynoEc/800x799",
        width: 1,
        height: 1
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/qDkso9nvCg0/600x799",
        width: 3,
        height: 4
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/iecJiKe_RNg/600x799",
        width: 3,
        height: 4
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/epcsn8Ed8kY/600x799",
        width: 3,
        height: 4
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/2ShvY8Lf6l0/800x599",
        width: 4,
        height: 3
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/Dm-qxdynoEc/800x799",
        width: 1,
        height: 1
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/qDkso9nvCg0/600x799",
        width: 3,
        height: 4
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/iecJiKe_RNg/600x799",
        width: 3,
        height: 4
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/epcsn8Ed8kY/600x799",
        width: 3,
        height: 4
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/2ShvY8Lf6l0/800x599",
        width: 4,
        height: 3
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/Dm-qxdynoEc/800x799",
        width: 1,
        height: 1
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/qDkso9nvCg0/600x799",
        width: 3,
        height: 4
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/iecJiKe_RNg/600x799",
        width: 3,
        height: 4
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/epcsn8Ed8kY/600x799",
        width: 3,
        height: 4
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/2ShvY8Lf6l0/800x599",
        width: 4,
        height: 3
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/Dm-qxdynoEc/800x799",
        width: 1,
        height: 1
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/qDkso9nvCg0/600x799",
        width: 3,
        height: 4
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/iecJiKe_RNg/600x799",
        width: 3,
        height: 4
      },
      {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/epcsn8Ed8kY/600x799",
        width: 3,
        height: 4
      },
  ];

const BasicRows = () => <Gallery photos={photos} /> 


export function Gallery1 () {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("App");

        return (
           <BasicRows />

        )
    

}
```

Hi I would like to toggle between grid (only photos shown) and list (photo shown on the left and description of the image on the right) view, how should I go about doing it?
Let me know if its better / faster to go through via email as I don't get notification from stackoverflow. Thank you in advance

As of now this is the result from my code (the toggle is clickable but does not work):
[image]

Comment: Can you include the code for your gallery component as that is where the solution would need to be

Comment: @RichardHpa I included it at the bottom of the code

Answer (score 0):

The `Grid` element form materila-ui has an attribute called `direction` which can be set the values "row" and "column" to achieve the same effect that you are looking for. Here are some modifications that need to make to achieve it:

```
const [dir, setDir] = useState('row');
const onToggle = (value = 'row') => setDir(value);

...
<ToggleButton onClick={() => onToggle('row')} ...
<ToggleButton onClick={() => onToggle('column')} ...

<Grid
  container
  direction={dir}
>
  <Gallery1/> 
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have got the error useState' is not defined  no-undef
What should I put under const useState =...?

Comment: You can `import { useState } from 'react';` or directly use it as `React.useState`. :)

Comment: Hi, I tried but it doesn't work. Still is just a grid gallery regardless of which button I click. Do I need to change out my "const handleAlignment = (event, newAlignment) => {
          setAlignment(newAlignment);"?

Comment: No, we are already skiping the event, the first argument will be the newalignent. Please check this to verify if everything you setup is correct:https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#interactive

Comment: This is my current code:
    export function Rightpanel () {
        const classes = useStyles();
        const [alignment, setAlignment] = React.useState('left');

        const handleAlignment = (event, newAlignment) => {
          setAlignment(newAlignment);
          

        };

        const [dir, setDir] = useState('row');
        const onToggle = (value = 'row') => setDir(value);

    return(
...
...

Comment: <ToggleButton aria-label="left aligned" value="left" onClick={() => onToggle('row')} >
                            <FormatAlignLeftIcon />
                        </ToggleButton>
                        
                        <ToggleButton value="center" aria-label="centered" onClick={() => onToggle('column')}>
                            <FormatAlignCenterIcon />
                        </ToggleButton>

Comment: It runs but when I click the button, there is no changes to it.

Comment: would it be better to communicate via email?:) @Vijay Dev